# Stop AD account Accessing Server shares

Tags: high-sierra, user-account, osx-server

I have an Mac server running 10.13.6 on the latest build: 17G7024
I have been trying to sort out a few of its problems. But I have come across this this weird bug that I can't seem to fix.
If I connect to a share like this:

smb://server-name/Share-name

It will take a moment to connect but connect me to the server with out prompt for a password.

Secondly My AD account Connect to the Share but should not be able to as the ACL is a local account with No AD Accounts as part of it.

What could be causing this and What can I do to Fix It.

Many Thanks in Advance